# Spring Boot 1.5.x with Spring Data Cassandra 1.5.x is incompatible with Cassandra 2.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to upgrade to Spring Boot 1.5 with Spring Data Cassandra 1.5.x using Cassandra 2.1 but I get a startup error:

> Failed to instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]:
>   Factory method 'cassandraMapping' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/datastax/driver/core/DataType$CollectionType

Cassandra details:

> [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.15.1403 | DSE 4.8.9 | CQL spec 3.2.1 |
>   Native protocol v3]

How can I upgrade to Spring Boot 1.5?

Edit: Is there a way to use Spring Boot Dependencies 1.5 as a parent in my pom.xml but keep Spring Data Cassandra 1.4

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes but maybe I'm not asking the right question. Is there a way to use Spring Boot Dependencies 1.5 as a parent in my pom.xml but keep Spring Data Cassandra 1.4? I edited my question to reflect this change.

Comment: If my answer has helped, please give thumps up. Coming to your another question, yes, you can define your Spring data for Cassandra separately and give the version to it. Show me your XML.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the class you are looking for is not having any definition as the class is missing from the jar expected. You are using advance version of Spring data 1.5 for Cassandra and trying to connect to 2.1.15, this compatible only with Spring data 1.4.

You can either stay back in Spring data 1.4 or consider switching Cassandra from 2.1 to to 3.1.3

Spring Data Cassandra 1.5 is released which internally uses Cassandra java driver 3.1.3

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below dependency for Cassandra.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```